# different decimal points after doing pandas series calculation

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm trying to do a calculation within pandas series. There is no error in the code.

```
# create pandas series using dictionary
student1 = pd.Series({'science':100, 'english':80, 'math':90})
student2 = pd.Series({'math':80, 'science':90, 'english':80})

# calculate by score
addition = student1 + student2               
subtraction = student1 - student2            
multiplication = student1 * student2        
division = student1 / student2               

# series to dataframe
result = pd.DataFrame([addition, subtraction, multiplication, division], 
                      index=['addition', 'subtraction', 'multiplication', 'division'])
print(result)
```

And the outcome is as below.
I wonder why do all columns' decimal points are having different outcome.

```
                english      math      science
addition          160.0   170.000   190.000000
subtraction         0.0    10.000    10.000000
multiplication   6400.0  7200.000  9000.000000
division            1.0     1.125     1.111111
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing this simply:-

```
division = student1 / student2
```

make use of `round()` method:-

```
division=round(student1 / student2,2)
```

This is happening because of your division:-

```
student1 / student2
```

the above code gives:-

```
english    1.000000
math       1.125000
science    1.111111
dtype: float64
```

and `pandas` default value of precision is 6

Comment: I guess my question was not that clear, I know we can use round() method to  avoid this outcome but wonder why we get this kind of outcome.

Comment: Updated answer kindly have a look